# Is it necessary to push our code without using git add

Tags: git, github

Is it necessary to run **git add .** command because running **git commit -m "push"** and then **git push** command can also push our code to the remote repository without running **git add .**  command?

Comment: git add is only relevant in terms of what you will _commit_ into the revision you will create. When pushing, it has _no relevance_ because what will be pushed is what **is** the revision/revisions of a branch. Now, you can skip using `git add` if you mean to commit everything in a given moment (like `git commit -a -m "committing everything"`) but that's not the way you will want to work in the long run. I could decide to commit only some of the files that I have modified at a given moment in time.... or even **a section** of a modified file... and then you will want to use `git add`).

Comment: Also `git add .` only adds files from the current folder, so you will not always have this special case of adding.

Comment: Again, you are free to skip using the staging area.... I am not saying otherwise.... but in the long run, you will want to take advantage of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: **yes**, it is necessary to stage changes/files before you (1) commit and then (2) push them, otherwise they will not be pushed to the remote repository.

It is wrong that running `git commit -m "push"` and then `git push` command can also push your code to the remote repository without running `git add .`.

`git add` expects a list of files as a parameter. The `.` in `git add .` just says stage all current changes from the current folder.

Answer (score 0):

`git add .` - stages all edits from the current directory (that's what `.` stands for) 
`git commit -m "push'` - commits all files you've staged with the message (that's what (`-m`) stands for) "push" 
`git push` - pushes the commits you've added to the remote repository

- **It is necessary** to specify what files you want to `add` before `committing`, otherwise `git` would not know what modifications you want to save.
- If you want to add all files and commit using a single command use `git commit -am` (**note** that this shorter command will not stage untracked files (a new class for example)))

**EDIT**: Make sure to check @eftshift0 's comments for further explanation